# Is it possible to have Angular serve from a local host without showing ports?

Tags: angular

I have multiple apps that all run from the same subdomain/domain just fine:

```
company.myapp.com/app1
company.myapp.com/app2
company.myapp.com/app3
company.myapp.com/app4
```

I need to test some functionality using local storage / cookies locally which requires same domain. However, serving locally requires setting a different port for each application:

```
localhost:4200/app1
localhost:4300/app2
localhost:4400/app3
localhost:4500/app4
```

I can set a host to something like `mylocalapps.com` but that still requires a port to be used. I it possible to setup up my local serve to either use the same port OR just hide the port?

Comment: System 101, you'll need the port. I aint going to be your wife opening if you ring at your neighbours door.

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler I agree, I was hoping there's a way to mask it so cookies and local storage are stored to the same location just like on the server.